# Throttle in Django Rest Framweork if user is None during Oauth2 request with CLient Credentials

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, throttling, django-oauth

I am using Django Rest Framework with Django OAuth Toolkit for allowing external organization to request endpoints.

I am using Crendentials Client grant type to ask access token.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoEUO.png)

When i try request my endpoint I have this error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'.
The exception is raised in the get_cached_key function of the AnonThrottleClass.

In fact request.user is None with Client Credentials, so this function can not pass.

Here is my viewset :

```
class StudentViewSet(
mixins.CreateModelMixin,
mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
mixins.ListModelMixin,
mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
viewsets.GenericViewSet,):

serializer_class = StudentSerializer
authentication_classes = (OAuth2Authentication,)
permission_classes = (TokenHasScope,)
required_scopes = [
    oauth2_settings.READ_SCOPE,
    oauth2_settings.WRITE_SCOPE,
]
schema = is_schema_for_open_api_doc(True)
queryset = Student.objects.all()
```

Can you help me with this ?

Thank you !

Comment: If you don't want throttling to be applied to this API, you can override throttle_classes to be an empty list (on the viewset). Otherwise you will need to implement a custom throttle class and override `get_cache_key`

Comment: Thank you very much, for now, I do with your first response and I see later for custom throttle.